# How to pass struct into function that is in another function

Tags: pointers, struct

My code:

```
typedef struct{
    int rows;
    int cols;
}Map;

int get_value(Map *map, int r, int c) {
    int value = map->rows + map->cols
    return value;
}
```

When I use this function in another one, for example:

```
bool border(Map *map, int r, int c, int border)
int value = (get_value(&&map,r,c);
```

Then I get the error:

> label "map" used but not defined

Comment: Are all your code snippets in the same source file?

Comment: please add the full code, this code is not significant.